# Medieval Footwear in swamplands

Tags: physics, medieval, clothing

In my world, people live in a swamp where the ground is consistently covered in at least 4-5 in of water and occasionally higher, reaching up to the knees.

My Question is what kinds of medieval style footwear could my people wear that allows them to walk and **specifically run through the water** with little to no friction or drag.

I have considered a frictionless enchantment but run into problem with the footwear. I want them to be able to effectively grip the ground when running and walking but the friction on the bottom of the shoes would affect movement when the foot enters the water.

TLDR: How can I fix this problem of needing to remove friction to move through water yet keep friction to grip the ground without it interfering in movement. Am I overestimating the impact of the friction caused by the foot entering water?

Edit: I would like this footwear to be for hunters who will be quite active in the water and would like as little restriction of movement as possible.

If there are other ways to prevent restriction of movement, I am open to hearing them. However, one restriction is they cannot walk on water especially above knee deep water.

Comment: If the water is that deep people are not taking their feet out of the water, the the friction with the water is your biggest issue, and no there is nothing you can do about it without using magic.

Comment: These people will have major health problems with their feet in very short order if their lower calves are submerged in water for hours on end. If they are human, they will have to find a way to live above the water rather than within it.

Comment: Are you saying the entire community actually lives in submerged swamp land or that their villages and communities live are placed on patches of high ground and that they often have to work/travel through submerged ground?

Comment: I think medieval people can drain swamps which is what they would do.

Comment: There was a short story in Elder Scrolls 4: Oblivion which approached this question masterfully. Two blacksmiths were competing for a contract to equip an army for a swamp. One made a suit of enchanted armor of the finest steel with a burning great sword. The second blacksmith put together some comfortable leathers and hammered together a rusty hooked blade. In contest in a swamp ,the enchanted suit of armor clogged with grit and the burning blade extinguished when it hit the water - they had to carry the poor immobile guy out. Life lesson: you can't keep a swamp out, just protect against cuts

Comment: Friction is not what prevents movement through water, it's the mass of the water itself. If you are up to your knees in water, you are having to move a *lot* of extra weight to take a step.

Comment: Yep. https://www.livescience.com/28082-medieval-monks-cultivated-wetlands.html

Comment: The medieval Japanese created shoes that solved this problem,though for less water/mud. The geta clogs had one or two "teeth" on the sole to keep them out of a small amount of water or mud with low technology. An alternative might be to build floating bridges.

Answer (score 50):

Stilts is the obvious solution and was used in various swampy places to help people get around.

Not the sort of stilts we play with which would just get stuck, they used a third stabilising stick the same way we'd use a walking staff.

[image: Inhabitants of the Landes]

<sup>Inhabitants of the French [Landes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landes_de_Gascogne) (sometimes known as the Gascony Moors in English), by Jean Louis Gintrac (first half of the 19th century). Reproduction [available on Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:GintracLandes.jpg), public domain.</sup>

Comment: Its worth noting stilts only work in sandy marshland (moors), in silty swamps they actually become counterproductive.  so the type of land matters. but +1 for remembering the french town of stilt walkers.

Comment: I kind of doubt stilts were seriously used. They’d get stuck in soft ground and they are completely impractical for performing heavy work or walking long distances. There is a reason alpinists use snow shoes in deep snow and not stilts.

Comment: @Michael it's a bit silly to doubt. Facts are that they were used for thousands of years. Look it up if you like.

Comment: As mentioned magic exist in this world. Can add enchantment to not go through land(sand, mud, foliage) but easy with water.

Comment: @Michael - a stilt walker walked from Paris to Moscow (roughly 3000km) on stilts in 58 days: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/13640/13640-h/13640-h.htm#misc2

Comment: @NeilTarrant A guy [ate an airplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Lotito). So it's completely feasible that there are whole villages of people eating airplanes.

Comment: @pipe But if you google "eat airplane", you find a reference to that one guy, and only that one guy, doing it as a stunt.  If you google "gascony stilt walkers", you get numerous links to articles about this being highly traditional as everyday "personal transport" in the region. including photographs and many historical documents.  In other words, the evidence supports one guy eating an airplane, and an entire region of stilt walking shepherds.

Comment: @NeilTarrant Ah yes, the great Russo-Francian silt marsh.

Answer (score 20):

This is how south Louisiana was for a long time. The solution they used was wide bottomed boats called pirogues. They didn't walk in the water, they floated above it. With a boat, they can move goods to market. If they had to walk, practically no goods would be able to get to market as they would have to carry them.

Comment: And here was me thinking a Pirogue was a type of Polish dumpling.

Comment: @Daron From the standpoint of etymology both words, 'pierog' (that very dumpling), and 'pirogue', stem from the same root.

Answer (score 12):

**Minecraft Frost Walker Boots**

[image]

In Minecraft, frost walker boots freeze a small area around you allowing you to run over the top of the water. The ice quickly melts when you stop moving.

A similar enchantment would allow people to move faster because they don't actually enter the water.

Comment: I have a feeling that the frost walker boot is not medieval...

Comment: @justhalf the OP discussed enchantments, so magic is allowed.

Answer (score 7):

People working in rice paddies do exactly this all the time and have for centuries. Looks like mostly rubber boots or barefoot.

Comment: Do exactly what? Are you reacting to another answer? And what looks like mostly rubber boots or barefoot?

Comment: Rubber seems too high-tech. If they wore something, could be warajis instead.

Comment: @Joachim Read the question. OP says "My Question is what kinds of medieval style footwear could my people wear that allows them to walk and specifically run through the water with little to no friction or drag."

Comment: While this is what people wear (or don't) while working in water, this doesn't address being able to move swiftly through the water, which the body of the question is asking.   The title probably does need updated to include that part of the question.

Comment: Rubber didn't exist in the medieval period. It started being used around in the 19th Century.

Answer (score 5):

**Inuit style clothing i.e. Waders**;  waterproofed waders and (in the event of rain) jackets made from treated animal skins, carefully stitched together and then sealed with animal fat to preserve watertight integrity.

A little research will show you there's a lot of photographs of the type of clothing I'm talking about on-line. Although I suspect it would degrade much more quickly in the type of environment your describing it should still 'work'  effectively if the owners took care to maintain it and waterproof it regularly.

For that matter if the water is usually only a few inches deep on average animal skin 'gum boots' would do.

Or if the climate is mild enough for most of the year **just go barefoot** and wear no clothing below the knee unless there's some overriding reason why they shouldn't.

Comment: One likely overriding reason to avoid going barefoot: Leeches or [parasites that enter through the soles](https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/strongyloides/index.html).

Comment: Possibly, but parasites and other potentially dangerous animals.diseases, weren't mention in the question and regardless of the terrain medieval societies tended to have significant problems with parasites anyway due to hygiene and medical issues.

Answer (score 0):

## Water strider shoes

Instead of magically reducing the friction, you change the surface tension of the water.  (The shoes are also pretty wide, reducing the mojo requirements)  The shoes could even *increase* the friction, since our experience walking on frozen water in the wintertime is that it's none too fun.  But that's rather inefficient, and we don't really need to go to a six-legged gait for balance.  Instead, the natives carry around a gyroscope, held onto them by clothing near their spine, against which they can apply torque so that they can shift their center of balance in any direction.  With a little practice alternating positions (so as not eventually to push the gyroscope over), they can use the angle of their body to glide rapidly in any direction.

*Note: I think the energy of the gyroscope is being used up to cause this propulsion against the tilted surface of the bent water.  Perhaps we should put some boss office desk toy enchantment on it so it never stops spinning.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a frame change.
Consider the [Sweet track](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_Track) It is a path made circa 3800BC to allow people to traverse marshlands.

Not footwear, but definitely was used by people to speed traversal of a marsh.

Answer (score -1):

I would think of thick-heeled boots that distribute the weight evenly. A cane or a walking stick, as another answer stated, would work well in conjunction with these boots.

Comment: on mud swamp shoes are a good idea in a foot of water they will be no help and instead will be a hinderance.